# Make columns stack vertically in Bulma when width is narrow?

Tags: html, css, bulma

The following is part of my website. What it is supposed to do is create two side-by-side regions when there is sufficient width. Otherwise, the regions should be stacked on top of each other.

```
<body>
    <div id="tab-container" class="tabs is-centered is-small is-fullwidth is-marginless is-paddingless">
        <ul>
            <li id="1" class="is-active">
                <a>1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="2">
                <a>2</a>
            </li>
            <li id="3">
                <a>3</a>
            </li>
            <li id="4">
                <a>4</a>
            </li>
            <li id="5">
                <a>5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="columns is-paddingless is-marginless" style="background: yellow;">
            <div class="column is-paddingless is-half" style="background: indigo">
            </div>
            <div class="column is-paddingless is-half" style="background: black">
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
```

When the width is sufficient, the website looks ok:

[image]

However, when I shrink the website - and it transitions to stacked mode - the black and purple regions disappear.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post your CSS.